# How To Get SSL Working with Elastic Beanstalk, Route53 and Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudflare, amazon-route53

I am struggling to get SSL to work on an elastic beanstalk environment with the following configuration:

I have the domain hosted with GoDaddy, which I have routing through cloudflare, which then routes to Route53 with an A record pointing to my subdomain api.myapp.com (which points to my EB environment).

I am using Cloudflare's full E2E encryption, and am using the SSL certificate provided by cloudflare.

In my EB environment, I am using a Classic Load Balancer and have the following configuration (note: my application uses websockets hence the TCP port):

[image]

I've added the SSL certificate to the HTTPS configuration but when I navigate to api.myapp.com I am still getting the "your connection is not secure" in the browser.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that AWS doesn't allow the use of SSL certificates purchased from cloudflare anymore, so I solved it by provisioning one with CA on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

The free ssl from zerossl.com works. After the validation and others stuffs at the end you will get three files.

- Using AWS Console

Download the zip files containing certificate, chain and private. Goto AWS certificate manager -> import certificate -> add all the details -> review and import the certificate.

- Using AWS CLI, which will output the certificate identifier

  ```
   aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name ish --certificate-body file://certificate.crt --certificate-chain file://ca_bundle.crt  --private-key file://private.key
  ```

Goto AWS Console load balancer and select 443 HTTPs the recent certificate will be available which can be identified by an identifier provided on both the above cases. Apply changes and restart the env. The new certificate will be available.